# facebook app posting on the chronik with request

Tags: javascript, facebook

sorry for my bad english.

I have written a game with html/JS and i wan't to post the result from the player on his wall, but therefore i wan't to show him a request for permission this posting.

i have found some code from a tutorial, but it's not working here:

```js
window.top.location='<object type="text/html" data="http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=561601214890531&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/colormmmm&scope=publish_actions" ></object>';
```

i know, i have to fill and post an array with the data which i want to post then. But why the code above does not function? Thanks!

okay, this is my code actually. It works, but there is no request before posting:

```
      request['message'] = "I earned "+points+" Points in Color Stones.";         
         FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: request['message'] }, function(response) {
                                                                           if (!response || response.error) {
                                                                                alert('Could not Publish Data');
                                                                                 }
                                                                                 else {
                                                                                 alert("Message successfully posted to your wall");
                                                                                      }
                                                                                 });
```

Comment: why not use the javascript sdk for this? you don´t need to waste your time with custom solutions. for example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: thankyou, but the code which is present there does not helping me because it's only code for login and so on

Comment: i can see that you are somehow trying to login without the javascript sdk (your fist code part), so it should definitely help you to get your base code correct. most likely, you will be able to fix your problem, after understanding how the login stuff works with the javascript sdk. either way, if it works to post, then you are already logged in before...remove your app in your user settings and try again.

Comment: hello, i have remove the app from my startpage. then, i have select and restart the app. But it don't works. Posting is ok, but without request.

Comment: you have to remove the app here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications - and then try again.

Comment: btw, prefilling the message is not allowed. you will never get publish_actions approved with that code. you need to read the platform policy. why not forget about authorization anyway and just use the share dialog instead?